# Why does my PHP process exit while parsing XML and inserting into MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, symfony

First time using MongoDB and I have some behaviour I need help with.

Im parsing a big XML file (85GB) with PHP/Symfony command. For every 100 records I do a `$collection->insertMany($items, ['ordered' => false]);` command inserting the 100 records, reset the array and keep parsing.

For some reason the PHP command just stops when hitting around 706.400 records. I have no PHP error and no error from the MongoDB docker container. All I see is some warnings from MongoDB about slow queries and then the connection is ended. I tried running the script without calling MongoDB and it runs fine. Taking way longer and with a total of ~10million records. I have tried inserting 1, 100, 500 at a time with the same end result. When it hits around  ~700.000 inserts my MacBook fan gets crazy and the console command struggles (I have a progress bar running).

Looking at Activity Monitor RAM is doing fine, and there is a lot of CPU activity on the docker process. Should it really not be possible to do something like this on a MacBook pro with MongoDB? Parsing it without works fine.

This is my docker-compose;

```
version: "3.1"
services:

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: vehicle-registry-webserver
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - .:/application
          - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "8080:80"

    php-fpm:
      build: phpdocker/php-fpm
      container_name: vehicle-registry-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini

    mongodb_container:
      image: mongo:latest
      environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
      ports:
        - 27017:27017
      volumes:
        - mongodb_data_container:/data/db

volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
```

```
mongodb_container_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-24T13:27:54.850+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn28","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"symfony.Vehicle","command":{"insert":"Vehicle","ordered":false,"$db":"symfony","lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"0288c26c-99b2-472b-b645-5fc70e84db44"}}},"ninserted":50,"keysInserted":50,"numYields":0,"reslen":45,"locks":{"ParallelBatchWriterMode":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}},"ReplicationStateTransition":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Database":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Collection":{"acquireCount":{"w":1}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"flowControl":{"acquireCount":1,"timeAcquiringMicros":1473},"storage":{},"protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":714}}
```

```
mongodb_container_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2020-08-24T13:28:02.082+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn28","msg":"connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.18.0.2:45066","connectionCount":6}}
```

Any idea why? Am I hitting some limit with MongoDB?

[image: CPU usage before start]
[image: CPU usage while running and sudden increase in CPU]
[image: CPU usage when process is stopped]

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that didn't change the behaviour. I removed all console output from the command and it does the same. Around ~550.000 records I start getting slow query warnings from MongoDB and the CPU start making more noise. Inserts are slown down and in the end the process stops for some reason around ~700.000 records. Might be to OS that kills it... I dont know.

Comment: Track the resources like memory, disk, open files, etc. see if something is getting close to exhaustion.

Comment: @Joe I have added screenshots of CPU usage which is the only ressource I can see is  impacted. I tried looking in `system.log`  to see if the process was killed by the OS but I cant find any indications.

Comment: I tried giving docker access to 12 cores instead of 6 but the script still exits.

Comment: try to clear the entitymanager after each bulk, did you know this: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.batchinsert.php

Comment: @johnSmith I tried using BulkWrite as described here https://phppedia.com/en/tutorial/4143/using-mongodb with a `$manager->executeBulkWrite` every 5000 records. Behaviour is the same. It exits around 700.000 records. So not using the doctrine `DocumentManager` didn't seem to help.. so annoying. Both docker images PHP/Mongo keeps running.. its only the PHP process that ends.

Comment: Went back to Doctrine DocumentManager with this approach (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/batch-processing.html). Used less CPU power now but still stopped running at around 600.000 records.

Comment: Running the PHP script outside of docker with mongoDB within docker keeps everything going...